# Using Ruby on Rails wiselinks for a store locator

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a working list of stores that are paginated and when clicking on one it shows the store details.

At the side of the list (`#index`) and the details (`#show`) it has a map showing the location(s).

I'm now trying to apply the wiselinks gem so that the transition from list to details is done via ajax so that the map doesn't need to be reloaded.

My list and details pages use a `sub_level_layout` of the main `application` layout.

The `sub_level_layout` is as follows:

```
<div class="stores-container">
   # partial loaded here
</div>
<div class="map-container"></div>
```

I am just reloading `.stores-container` with the new information and when complete it automatically just shows the particular location(s) on the map.

I am currently using wiselinks to update the partial.

I declare wiselinks using:

```
$(function() {
  window.wiselinks = new Wiselinks();
});
```

My list and details links use `data-push='partial' data-target='.stores-container'`

My controller looks like this:

```
def index
  ...
  if request.wiselinks_partial?
    render :partial => 'my_partial'
  else
    render :layout => 'sub_level_layout'
  end
end

def show
  ...
  if request.wiselinks_partial?
    render :partial => 'my_partial'
  else
    render :layout => 'sub_level_layout'
  end
end
```

This works fine for clicking through pages of results on the index page and also allows me to click the link for one of the results to go to the show page.

However, it fails if I load the index page, click one of the results to display the show page and then click the back button. It doesn't seem to know what to use to render the index page it just shows a blank page.

I need it to just refresh the contents of the partial so that the index will be displayed again.

If I load the index page, click through to a different page (paging done using wiselinks as well), then click one of the results to display the show page and then click the back button it works fine.

It doesn't seem to like clicking the back button to go to the starting page (page initially loaded as html rather than via wiselinks) and only refreshing contents using a partial rather than the full screen.

When the page fails to load the headers for the fail request contain `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` and `X-Wiselinks:template`

Am I doing this correctly using wiselinks?

Is there another way to do it so it doesn't need to load the template from scratch when I click back to the starting page when I only need it to reload the partial?

I want to stay with wiselinks if possible.

Thanks

---

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

I think I've got it working now by changing:

```
$(function() {
  window.wiselinks = new Wiselinks();
});
```

to

```
$(function() {
  window.wiselinks = new Wiselinks($('.stores-container'));
});
```

and for my controller:

```
def index
  ...
  if request.wiselinks_partial?
    render :partial => 'my_partial'
  else
    render :layout => 'sub_level_layout'
  end
end

def wiselinks_layout
  'my_partial_as_a_layout'
end

def show
  ...
  if request.wiselinks_partial?
    render :partial => 'my_partial'
  else
    render :layout => 'sub_level_layout'
  end
end
```

New layout - `my_partial_as_a_layout.html.erb`:

```
<%= render 'stores/my_partial' %>
```

I don't like the way it requires me to replicate my partial as a layout in my layouts folder.

I also don't like the fact that this set of pages for the store locator need a specific div to be set as the container for wiselinks to work with even though each of the links has a `data-target` attribute set as `'.stores-container'` anyway.

Can someone either explain why this is possibly correct or what's wrong with it if it is still not right.

Thanks

Comment: I'm facing same issue, any resolutions to this :)!

Comment: Tried removing the `else` for `wiselinks_partial?` in the controller and not using a `wiselinks_layout` at all and I think it seems to work although using `html4:false` for wiselinks if that makes a difference.